# C# DataGridView Tab skip 1 Cell

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell, skip

I used this code to let the "Tab" Key get to the next Cell in the datagridview. The only problem is that it skips 1 Cell when the Cell enters in edit mode.
here is the code:

```
 private void entityLinesGrid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                int iColumn = entityLinesGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                int iRow = entityLinesGrid.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                if (iColumn == entityLinesGrid.Columns.Count - 1)
                {
                    
                    entityLinesGrid.CurrentCell = entityLinesGrid[0, iRow + 1];
                }
                else {entityLinesGrid.CurrentCell = entityLinesGrid[iColumn + 1, iRow];}
            }

        }
```

Comment: What I don't understand is.. Tab already behaves this way; you're inventing a wheel that doesn't need to be invented

Comment: It kinda does. The problem is when gets to the last row. Plus I needed to use it so it enters in edit mode as soon as the tab gets me to the cell by adding: dataGridView.BeginEdit(true);

Comment: I'm perhaps still not getting it. If I tab from eg a focused button into a DGV, the first cell (or previously focused cell) goes blue but I don't need to do anything to start editmode; i just type keys and the cell immediately goes to edit and accepts what I typed.. If you mean you want to lock focus into the DGV maybe it would be simpler to capture the focus lost, change the current cell to the first one(?) and refocus the DGV. Attempts to subvert the "press tab for next cell" behavior seldom work out well, alas

Comment: Probably I did something to the properties which doesn't make it work as default. Perhaps I will try to apply your advice! Thanks man!

Comment: (Might be worth dropping a single DGV on a new form, adding a few columns and then running the app and just use tab etc.. see how it behaves..)

Comment: Please forgive me if I am missing something. I agree with Caius that this seems like you are reinventing the wheel. I have seen where users want to “change” the behavior of some key like the “Enter” key to “act” like a “TAB” key, however, your code is simply mimicking what the TAB key would do anyway… which is… odd. You state that _”The problem is when gets to the last row.”_ … ? … and this “problem” would be … … ? …

Comment: Also confusing is your comment using the TAB key to set the cell into “edit” mode… _”Plus I needed to use it so it enters in edit mode as soon as the tab gets me to the cell by adding: dataGridView.BeginEdit(true);”_ … ? … I am not sure “why” you would need to drop the cell into “edit” mode since the grid will automatically drop that cell into “edit” mode as soon as the user “types” a single character.

Comment: Guess what, I did not know that as soon as you type in the cell automatically enters in edit mode... Sorry about the confusion...